# Dividir soma dos valores de um vetor

Tags: c, array

Estou tentando dividir/multiplicar todos os números entre si usando vetores.

por exemplo: digito 4 números e divido todos entre si: 5/5/2/1 porém não consigo obter a divisão. segue o programa:

```
float numeros[4];
float resultado;
float soma;

printf("digite 4 numeros: \n");

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    scanf("%f", &numeros[i]);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    soma += numeros[i];
    resultado = soma / numeros[i];
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que deseja calcular, inclusive não bate com a descrição, mas você não atribuiu um valor inicial à variável `soma` e portanto está partindo de lixo de memória.

Comment: eu quero dividir mais de um numero ao mesmo tempo. Por exemplo: o programa pede 3 numeros e dividem eles, tipo 4 / 3 / 2

Comment: não sei se é possível dessa forma, queria saber

Comment: Ao mesmo tempo não é possível, consecutivamente é possível, primeiro 4/3 depois o resultado dividido por 2 e assim sucessivamente. Isto pode ser feito na mesma operação `resultado = 4 / 3 / 2;` que é equivalente a `resultado = (4 / 3) / 2;`. Não considerando que você possa estar pensando em um programa com diferentes threads fazendo as divisões em paralelo.

Comment: entendi. Muito obrigado amigo

Answer (score 0):

> da próxima vez posta o código em si e não uma imagem

Não sei se entendi muito bem mas por exemplo vc recebe os numero 10,2,3,5 e que dividi-los na ordem ou seja `( ( ( 10/2 )/3 )/5 )`.... é isso ?

se for  há alguns problemas ....

1º em c as variáveis devem ser inicializadas com um valor para evitar lixo de memoria ou seja

```
float resultado = 0;
float soma = 0;
```

o segundo problema é que sua logica esta errada existe um caso base que é o primeiro numero e ele não é divisivel por nada, ou seja quando vc recebe o primeiro numero que no exemplo seria 10 você não o divide por nada  e ficaria assim

```
 resultado = numero[0];
```

a partir do segundo numero que vc começa a dividir

```
for( var i=1 ; i<4 ; i++){
   resultado = (resultado/numero[i]);
}
```

OBS: faz um bom tempo que não programo em c porem a logica  é essa e me desculpe por erros de sintaxe

Comment: ficou bem clara a sua explicação amigo!